# How can I ingest a file in Azure?

Tags: azure, visual-studio

So like using console apps is StreamReader(file path), but how do read the path in Azure?

Comment: You're question is too broad: what Azure technologies are you referring to ?

Comment: Function Apps, Logic Apps, Storage Account.
File is in Storage Account.
Function Apps is triggered by Logic App.

Comment: It is mentioning about ingesting a .txt file in Azure.

Comment: Store in Azure, ingest into C#.

Comment: Like what I did for the console app, except now, I have to read it from file storage instead.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide these details - explain the architecture